# Computed Column Formula

Tags: sql-server, formula, calculated-columns

I've created a computed column with this formula:

```
(CONVERT([datetime],(CONVERT([varchar],[TradeDate])+' ')+CONVERT([varchar],[TradeTime])))
```

but when I save the table, the formula automatically changes to:

```
(CONVERT([datetime],(CONVERT([varchar],[TradeDate],0)+' ')+CONVERT([varchar],[TradeTime],0),0))
```

So it causes this problem:

Suppose `TradeDate` is: `2012-08-13` and `TradeTime` is: `10:29:59.0000000`

and instead of showing `2012-08-13 10:29:59.000`, it shows `2012-08-13 10:29:00.000`, because of changing the formula.

What's the solution?

Comment: What **datatype** are your `TradeDate` and `TradeTime` columns? Also: when converting to `VARCHAR`, you should **always** define a **length** for the `VARCHAR(x)` result!

Comment: And also: what **version** of SQL Server (2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012) are you using?

Comment: TradeDate is date and TradeTime is time(7). SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `(CONVERT([datetime],[TradeDate],0)+CONVERT([datetime],[TradeTime],0))`

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server adds `0` to your convert expression because that is the default style which represents Datetime in the format `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)`

The 3rd parameter in your convert function represents style.So `0 or 100` represents default style .So u can specify the style when creating the computed column .

[CAST and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)